# Pipeline connectivity

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geometric-network

I'm trying to find a way to determine pipeline connections located downstream a critical facility and score how far those connections are from the facility. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could use network analyst. First create a network out of your pipeline files. Then Load a closest facility problem and drop your incidents at the end of each pipeline you want to measure.  Your facility will be the main facility.  In the accumulation tab under properties of the closest facility in the TOC you can set your accumulation to feet or miles or whatever you want distance in.  Then solve the network problem and Then right click on routes in the TOC and you will see a table called Total_Length or Total_Cost or something similar, that will be your distance from the pipeline to the endpoint along the pipeline route.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ArcGIS-DeskTop 10.2 for reference. In ArcToolBox go to Analysis tools. Inside of the Proximity envelope there is a tool called 'Generate Near Table'. This tool will generate a table output containing the standard OBJECTID field, an IN_FID field for the input feature, NEAR_FID for the near feature input, a NEAR_DIST field for the distance the near feature is from the input feature, and a NEAR_RANK field to rank the closest/farthest features. Make a selection of the facility you wish to use, the tool will only use that feature from the input. Then add the near input feature and specify the output table path. At the bottom of the window there is a  "Find only closest feature" option, uncheck it so that you will get a list of all near features. Here is a link to the tool help:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Generate_Near_Table/00080000001n000000/
I hope this helps you in your endeavor.

Comment: This will give the distance between the facility and the connection as the crow flies, not along the pipeline's actual route.