# Critical facility pipe connections in python

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I'm trying to find a way to determine pipeline connections located downstream a critical facility and score how far those connections are from the facility.

Is there a way to accomplish the above task with python? I have a shapefile and would like to work with that to write a script in python.

Comment: Please don't capitalize your text, it is interpreted as screaming and commonly considered rude in the internet.

Comment: Sorry, did not mean that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pipeline connectivity](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154852/pipeline-connectivity)

Answer (score 1):

There is a python module called [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html) which is able to work on directed graphs.

The basic concept is:

1. Add all nodes to the graph (`add_node`)
2. Add all edges to the graph (`add_edge`)
3. Run [`bellman_ford`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.bellman_ford.html) on the graph

It has successfully been used to find downstream reaches and wastewater structures in wastewater networks in the [QGEP project](https://github.com/QGEP/QGEP/blob/master/qgepplugin/tools/qgepnetwork.py) (link points to relevant code) which is a QGIS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The python script is here at the bottom of the page http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004800000028000000

First create a network out of your pipeline.  You may have to export to a feature class and do it from there, I am not sure if it works on shapefiles.

then create a seperate shapefile/featureclass with your incidents and load them in the script where called for (these incidents will be a point at the end of each pipe you want to analyse) then load your facility which would be the main facility.

set your distance & accumulate attributes to feet or miles or whatever you want the distance measured in.